# Use both Recursive Feature Eliminiation and Grid Search in SciKit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a machine learning problem and want to optimize my SVC estimators as well as the feature selection.

For optimizing SVC estimators I use essentially the code from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_digits.html#example-model-selection-grid-search-digits-py). Now my question is, how can I combine this with [recursive feature elimination cross validation (RCEV)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_with_cross_validation.html#example-feature-selection-plot-rfe-with-cross-validation-py)? That is, for each estimator-combination I want to do the RCEV in order to determine the best combination of estimators and features.

I tried the solution from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784392/how-can-i-avoid-using-estimator-params-when-using-rfecv-nested-within-gridsearch), but it yields the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter C for estimator RFECV. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

My code looks like this:

```
tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-4,1e-3],'C': [1,10]},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'],'C': [1, 10]}]

estimator = SVC(kernel="linear")
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=3, scoring=None)
clf = GridSearchCV(selector, tuned_parameters, cv=3)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The error appears at `clf = GridSearchCV(selector, tuned_parameters, cv=3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Pipeline, but here you have a more adequate response

[Recursive feature elimination and grid search using scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815938/recursive-feature-elimination-and-grid-search-using-scikit-learn)

Comment: thanks. i also got it to work with this tutorial: https://civisanalytics.com/blog/data-science/2016/01/06/workflows-python-using-pipeline-gridsearchcv-for-compact-code/ (it also uses pipelines).